# How can I convert the data from a DocumentSnapshot to a custom type using Google Cloud functions so I can take advantage of autocomplete?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, typescript-typings

I really like the fact that firebase has some really nice typings when developing cloud functions in typescript. I want to be able to use auto complete with the entities in my db like users, etc. How can I create the classes correctly?

I think it should be something like this

```
type User = {
  activeUntil: admin.firestore.Timestamp
  createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp
  sex: 'men' | 'woman'
  name: string
}

export default async function onCreate (snap : FirebaseFirestore.DocumentSnapshot) {
    const user:User= snap.data()
    console.log('user:- ', user)
    return
}
```

I get Error:  I get the following error: Type 'DocumentData' is missing the following properties from type 'User': activeUntil, createdAt, sex, name.

Comment: What's wrong with what you've written so far?

Comment: Sorry that I wasnt clear. I get the following error: Type 'DocumentData' is missing the following properties from type 'User': activeUntil, createdAt, sex, name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your document fields are exactly matched to a type or interface description, you can simply cast the DocumentData object returned by `snap.data()` to that type.

```
const user = snap.data() as User
```

Bear in mind that any inconsistencies at runtime might cause a problem, for example, missing document fields, or unexpected strings in your union type.  It can be convenient to simply do the cast, but you need to be very confident that everything will conform to the shape of the type or interface.

Comment: Is it considered a bad practice to do it that way? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I can't speak to best practice. The option is there if you want to use it.  If you want to be bulletproof, you should check everything coming from the database before you cast it, since Firestore can't make any guarantees about the types of data in each field.

Comment: What happens if the saved is Map<String, dynamic>?

Answer (score 2):

### Firestore Data Converter Function

First, we'll define a Firestore data converter function that converts Firestore data to and from TypeScript types. This function makes use of Firestore's `withConverter` method to automatically parse Firestore documents into TypeScript interfaces.

```js
/**
 * Create a Firestore data converter for a specific data type.
 */
export function converter<T extends DocumentData>() {
  return {
    /**
     * Converts data of type T to Firestore format.
     */
    toFirestore(data: T): DocumentData {
      return data;
    },
    /**
     * Converts Firestore snapshot data to the specified data type T.
     */
    fromFirestore(
      snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>
    ): T {
      return snapshot.data() as T;
    },
  };
}
```

### Define Firestore Document Interfaces

Now, you can define Firestore document interfaces that extend the `DocumentData` type. These interfaces represent the structure of your Firestore documents.

```js
import { DocumentData } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';

/**
 * Interface representing a user document in Firestore.
 */
export interface IUser extends DocumentData {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

### Usage

With the Firestore data converter function and Firestore document interfaces in place, you can now work with Firestore data in a strongly-typed manner. Here's an example of how to retrieve Firestore documents with type safety:

```js
import { firebase } from 'firebase-admin';
import { converter, IUser } from './your-file-path';

const ref = firebase()
  .firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .withConverter(converter<IUser>())
  .doc('sample-user-id');

const user = await ref.get();
// 'user' is now of type 'IUser'.
```